# Как подключаться к sql-файлам и передавать им значения?

Tags: mysql, sql

В курсах  "специалиста" по ajax слышал, что можно и нужно работать с MYSQL с помощью одного sql. А как тогда подключаться к sql-файлам и как туда передавать значения переменных с javascript?

Comment: > работать с MYSQL с помощью одного sql

Вот эту строчку надо объяснить подробнее, пушо ничего не понятно. Через одну точку входа?

> как тогда подключаться к sql файлам и как туда передавать значения переменных с javascript.

SQL-файлы, как правила, содержат только данные и команды по изменению структуры, т.е. их можно выполнять внутри базы данных, но вот подключаться к ним вряд ли можно, равно ка и передавать в них значения.

Comment: Либо курсы низкопробные, либо Вы что-то не то поняли, либо не поняли, либо это не Ваше.